# Bash script hangs

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I have the code below. Basically this code will `ls -tr $FROM_DIRECTORY` then redirect the output to `/tmp/msc.load.tmp`. After this a `for` loop will execute and move the first 3000 files to another directory. The code is working fine but sometimes it will hang. I have no idea why it hangs. Anyone know what is the problem of the script?

```
ls -tr $FROM_DIRECTORY > /tmp/msc.load.tmp
echo "$sysdate -- Listing Diretory " >>$LOGFILE
# From the file list, get the 3000 from the top to move. Skip the remaining files in the list 
# in this iteration. 
# Version 1.1 - List the files from the temporary file.  
for file in $(cat /tmp/msc.load.tmp | grep 'MSCERC.*' | head -3000 )
do 
   mv $FROM_DIRECTORY/$file $DESTINATION_DIRECTORY
done
echo "$sysdate -- End of Script " >>$LOGFILE
exit 0
# End of script.
```

Comment: It would be better to just use the `find` command and dispense with the intermediate file.

Comment: run it with "bash -x" so you'll be able to see where and probably why did it hang

Comment: I new to unix..May i know how to add -x in the script ? Can gv some example ?

Comment: The `cat`, the `head`, and the regex wildcard are all unnecessary.  Also, [don't read lines with `for`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) `grep -m 3000 MSCERC /tmp/msc.load.tmp | while read -r file; do` ... Finally, [quote your variables.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642)

Answer (score 4):

Yeap, try a find.

Also if you're not aware of it, the `set -x` command is valuable in situations like this. My approach is to add `set -x` to the top of the script and then run it with output redirected to a file. capturing both standard out and standard error

```
./script.sh > output.txt 2>&1
```

If you want you can `tail -f output.txt` in another window to monitor progress.

`set -x` echos the commands run and the redirection puts the command and output into chronological order.

Comment: Which part guarantees that stdout and stderr will be in chronological order?

Comment: The writing of lines cronologically.  As opposed to trying to relate the stderr from the console and stdout from a redirect without the stderr part.

Comment: But there are still no guarantees that they will be written out in sync. I mean, yes, it's better than having them go to two separate destinations, but if the streams are flooded then they will not necessarily be output in order. But I guess the asker will have to take their chances.

Comment: I new to unix..May i know how to set -x in the top of the script ? Can gv some example ?

Comment: Either call the script with the -x parameter as hmontoliu says above or edit your script and above the line 
  ls -tr $FROM_DIRECTORY > /tmp/msc.load.tmp
enter
  set -x